# Get encoder version in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I can check if the encoder is available with `ffmpeg -encoders | grep lame`, but how do I find out the version of it?

In the case of LAME I can open a converted audio file with a text editor and find the version there, but I'd like to know if FFmpeg can give me codec version info right away, without resorting to hacks?

Comment: Note that ffmpeg will be using a particular version of an *encoder* (and *decoder*) only. A *codec* doesn't have a software version, as it's a more abstract concept.

Comment: @slhck, thank you for the correction, I edited the post to only name it encoder.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `ffmpeg` does not have the info. The version of your decoder/encoder depends on what library you decided to install on your OS. So, on Ubuntu, you would get the codec version from your package manager like so:

```
$ ffmpeg -v quiet -codecs |grep lame
DEA.L. mp2                  MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2) (decoders: mp2 mp2float ) (encoders: mp2 mp2fixed libtwolame )
DEA.L. mp3                  MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3) (decoders: mp3 mp3float ) (encoders: libmp3lame libshine )
$ apt search libmp3lame
...
libmp3lame0/xenial,now 3.99.5+repack1-9build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  MP3 encoding library
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of using an internal, native FFmpeg encoder, such as `-c:a aac` (as opposed to an encoder from an external library, for example libmp3lame), you can refer to the libavcodec version number as shown in the console output when using the `ffmpeg` tool. It's not necessarily a codec "version", but it will give you a general idea of when in the FFmpeg version timeline the file is from. Example:

```
libavcodec     57. 95.101 / 57. 95.101
```

If you're using the FFmpeg libav* libraries, refer to the version header for each library, such as `libavcodec/version.h`.

If you have a file encoded with `ffmpeg`, depending on the output format,  it will often provide the muxer version in the file metadata. Example:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
```